# Turn on a circuit, using Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2, hardware

I successfully learned how to turn on an LED. Now, having a battery and a motor, I want to turn on the circuit using the Pi: basically starting the motor when I send a signal from Pi, but *not* sending current to the motor itself.

I want the Pi to only send the signal that I want to power the motor using the battery.

How can I do that?

A simple way would be just using an electromagnet which will turn on the circuit mechanically, but I want to use an electric component if possible.

Comment: You could use a [MOSFET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET) as a switch to turn the motor on/off.

Comment: Despite the mentioning of 12V in the linked question, the idea and the answers are quite fitting.

Comment: @Ghanima Well, the motor thing was just an example. Another example would be to turn on any circuit, like a programatic switch. Would that work in general? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a MOSFET, as suggested by @Ron-Beyer

[image: MOSFET]

But if it's a heavy motor you'll need to consider a opto isolated relay.
(the modern version of closing a curcuit with a electro magnet, still the same technique)

[image: Relay]

And if the motor is so big, that the inrush current might get a problem : use a solid state relay!
[image: Solid State Relay]